# Thermal printer Bangla Font Print dont working in Java

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer

I'm beginner in thermal printer, I m trying to print Bangla in Thermal printer when print result is: 
[image: After Print]
I'm try with also other charset,
How can solve this? Thanks in advance.

My Code Here :
Main.java

```
private void print(){

   PrintDefault pd=new PrintDefault();
    String Str2 = null;
    String text = null;
    text = "আপনি কি ডাটা সংরক্ষন করতে চান";
    pd.printString(Str2+"\n");
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bos.reset();
    bos.write(29);
    bos.write((int)'V');
    bos.write(1);

    byte[] cutPaper=bos.toByteArray();

    pd.printBytes(cutPaper);

}
```

PrintDefault.java

```
public void printString(String text) {


      DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    try {

        byte[] bytes;
        // important for umlaut chars
        bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
        job.print(doc, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void printBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    try {

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
        job.print(doc, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `System.out.println(text)` print in standard output?

Comment: Output same to text string , This is output for System.out.println(text)
আপনি কি ডাটা সংরক্ষন করতে চান